# My LCD is Glowing-- Is It Because My Eyes are Strained, or the LCD is Aging?

Tags: lcd

I got a LCD back in 2004 ( [SyncMaster 710v](http://www.dooyoo.co.uk/tft-monitor/samsung-syncmaster-710-v/)) . It was working fine, but recently I found it exceptionally glowing, causing great discomfort and tiredness to my eyes.

Since I face the LCD all the time, I'm not sure whether my discomfort is because of long hours facing the LCD, or is it that the LCD is defective? As far as I know LCD should *never* cause eye strain.

Comment: I'd get your eyes checked. How long is it since your last checkup? In the UK they recommend every two years.

Comment: I'm not sure about that; I've no problem reading small font letters, and I don't need specs to read newspaper.

Comment: @Ngu - Regardless, I'd still recommend a visit to an optician.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things, get someone else to look at it, if they say it is glowing - monitor. If they say it is normal - optician!

Answer (score 4):

Not directly answering the question, but you might want to try [F.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/), which:

> makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.

[image]

Comment: That was my first thought too. Has Ngu Soon Hui recently been working unusual hours? If so, the differing light conditions are a good bet.

I find that my monitor looks quite different through the day.

Comment: Regardless of whether you're experiencing issues, **Check this stuff out**. F.lux is fantastic. It got on my "to donate" list within minutes of seeing what it really did.

Comment: Think I got the idea from you, Phoshi. It is wonderful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the brightness (you might need to turn it down--LCDs are usually overbright at default settings).  I've had to turn down the brightness on my monitors more recently (I didn't originally feel the need to).
You might even consider recalibrating the whole thing to achieve the optimal picture quality.  [Jeff Atwood posted about calibration a while ago](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000965.html), and you can also use some test pattern images over at [this site](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/).